# Annoying Encoding Issue

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, encoding, character

I checked the solutions of this, couldnt find anything usefull on my problem.
I have to use Turkish characters like `"ş,Ş,ğ,Ğ,ü,Ü,ö,Ö,ç,Ç"` when I open a file and write something into the file. But here is my problem:

```
with open("file1.txt","a","utf-8-sig") as f:
    f.write(u"ŞşşĞĞğğğüüüÜÜİİİii")
```

I get this error every time:

```
  with open("file1.txt","a","utf-8-sig") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It's really annoying. I tried everything.

This is how I start my Python scripts:

```
# -*- coding: cp1254 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
from __future__ import division
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

I can't encoding the file. if I try this:

```
with open("file1.txt","a",encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What can I do for encoding in Pyhon3x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 2, the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) takes no `encoding` argument. The third argument is the *buffering* option instead.

You appear to be confused with the *Python 3 version*. If so use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead:

```
import io

with io.open("file1.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
```

In Python 3, the `io.open()` function replaced the version from Python 2.

You may want to study up on Unicode and Python:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: @qqvc: did you read the whole answer? There *is no such argument*. You are using the wrong function.

Comment: with open("file1.txt","a","utf-8-sig") as f:
TypeError: an integer is required   did you see this?

Comment: Yes, and did you read my answer? The third argument is the buffering argument. The Python 2 version of `open()` takes *no encoding argument*.

Comment: so what will I do? I cant encode a file? I tried io.open, still it wants an integer

Comment: @qqvc: one last time: read *carefully*. I use the `encoding` keyword.

Comment: @qqvc: if you look at the documentation for `io.open()` you'll see that the third *positional* argument is still the buffering option.

Comment: @qqvc that would a new problem. You are mixing byte strings and unicode somewhere now.

Comment: Im using f.write(u"somethingsomething") its about that "u"? Im really sick of this character problem. Whatever I tried, its not fixing.

Comment: @qqvc yes you do need to write unicode data when opening a file object with an encoding. For data already encoded open the file in binary mode without an encoding.

Comment: so I remove that "u" and I got this: TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Comment: its a bloody paradox. whatever I do, still I got an error.

Comment: @Beginner that wouldn't produce Unicode either. Just whacking it down to ASCII bytes is not a solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I realized that as soon as I tested it. Just that that solution worked great for me when I was working with `UTF - 8` characters

Comment: if I ignore the ascii error, then how can I write my words to file? I have to write Turkish characters to a file as I said..

Comment: @qqvc I suggest you create a new question with more detail as to what you are doing. This specific issue (how to open a file object that writes unicode to disk a UTF8) is now solved but clearly you are still struggling with producing the unicode data to write to the file. Include enough code and data to reproduce your new error.

Comment: Yes Martin is right.  I copy your program, and got it running without any error.   Just use Python 3 (mine is 3.6.7 Anaconda).